# Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé game with winning strategy restriction

Tags: logic, graph-theory, first-order-logic

I'm recently working on a proof about EF Game with some restrictions.

Given a structure C. A C-restricted winning strategy for the spoiler is a winning strategy, in which the spoiler only pick the elements in C.

Now I have two structures, A and B, which must be graphs. I need to show that for every m > 2 there exist the structures A and B, so that neither A- nor B-resricted winning strategy for the spoiler in a m round EF game. But there is a winning strategy for the spoiler when m = 2.

Here's my approach:
First: I show that the spoiler always win in 2 moves(with non restricted winning strategy).
Then: I show that when m > 2, the spoiler can only win non-restrictedly. That means if the spoiler play either A- or B-restricted game, he will lose and the duplicator will win.

Although I already have an approach, I can't find the suitable structures for A and B, I have tried almost every graph and none of them works. Though I have found the suitable graphs for m=2 [image: Graphs for m = 2]

However I have no idea how to continue and have been struggling for days. So any help and tips would be very appreciated! :D

Answer (score 4):

Here's an outline of how to get a pair of graphs which work for **every** $m$ at once! Of course these graphs have to be infinite, but I think ultimately this will clarify things substantially.

---

The key point is to note that restricted EF-games can be thought of as generalized embeddings: if $\mathfrak{A}$ embeds into $\mathfrak{B}$, then for every $n$ Duplicator wins the restricted-to-$\mathfrak{A}$ EF-game.

(Here I use "embed" in the strong sense: an embedding is an injection which preserves *and reflects* edge relationships, so $aEb\color{red}{\iff} f(a)Ef(b)$.)

Now bi-embeddability is actually not as strong a condition as one might think! There are very different structures which are nonetheless bi-embeddable. For example - and this actually takes us very close to the answer to your question - we can show:

> There are graphs $\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B}$ which are bi-embeddable but such that $\mathfrak{A}$ is connected and $\mathfrak{B}$ is not connected.

(Of course they have to be infinite - for *finite* graphs, bi-embeddability is the same as isomorphism.)

HINT: think about taking an existing disconnected graph, and adding a new point $*$ and an edge connecting $*$ to each existing point. This shows how you can embed a disconnected graph in a connected graph, and playing around with this you should be able to come up with an example of the type above.

Now as to your actual problem, you want to combine this idea with **preventing** $2$-equivalence. Think about **distance** between nodes in a graph - when we adjoined $*$ in the paragraph above, we didn't just get a connected graph, we got a connected graph of diameter $2$ ...